# Clickable command in text Discord

Tags: discord, command, click, slash

I saw a YouTube video that shows you a way to display a "slash command" on Discord (see Image 1)

[image: A hoverable slash command]

by sending "</any text:0>" (not clickable). I tried with any number at the end and its still working. So I tested </a slash command in my bot:MY BOT ID> and it was still working but it is not clickable.

Does anyone know a way to make a clickable slash command like in verified Discord bot profiles?

[image: clickable slash commands]

I am not sure it's possible but if someone knows how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't control the 'Try my commands' section from appearing on your bot's profile. Discord will generate that section for your bot after a while of your bot being online & used.

---

In order to put clickable slash command buttons as you've shown you need to use the application command ID, not the bot id. You can find that by clicking on the prompt:

[image]

You can then take that ID to form `</fast:972289487818334212>`, which will be a clickable form of slash command.

Please note that slash command ids are changed randomly and frequently on Discord's end.

Comment: Yes I know you don't answer to my question lol. I want to send a text with a clickable slash command

Comment: @Kodeur_Kubik Apologies, I didn't understand what you were asking. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Oh yes it's working! Thank you so much! I am sorry, English is the third language I speak so it is not easy to say everything lol

Comment: Idk if you gonna read this comment but do you know how to get this ID directly in Discord.js?

Answer (score 1):

For sub-commands, you can do as such:

```markdown
</cool-bot settings:2046185065514240342>
```

The command ID can be found under `message.data.id`, when your server receives a command.